# PerformSelectorInBackground leaking on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, multithreading, memory

While it seems to not pose a problem on the simulator, using `performSelectorInBackground` on the device causes memory leaks. Or at least that's what Instruments indicates. Looking at the  code I don't have a single clue what the cause could be.
I tried to strip the affected code to a bare minimum but still strangely Instruments keeps showing a leak every time this piece of code is executed.

Anything unusual going on here?

```
 //In viewcontrollerA:
    -(void)mainLoop
    {
     [self.viewControllerB performSelectorInBackground:@selector(calculateTotals) withObject:nil];

            //This gives the same problem
         //[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(calculateTotals) toTarget:self.viewControllerB withObject:nil];

            //UI stuff ...

    }

    //viewControllerB:
    -(void)calculateTotals
    {
     NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

     //Heavy calculations ...


     [pool release];
    }
```

**Edit:**
I'm still looking into this and it seems that the leak is caused by the fact that somewhere down the stack [NSThread start] is never followed by [NSThread exit]. So it appears like there is occasionally a thread which is kept running without ever ending it.
Now my question is, is there something I could do to make end those 'hanging' threats manually?

Comment: What kind of object does Instruments say is being leaked?

Comment: My off-the-cuff guess is that it's a retain cycle from performSelectorInBackground retaining it's target, this article might be helpful: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-04-30-dealing-with-retain-cycles.html

Comment: @kperryua It says the leaks are originating from 'GeneralBlock-3584', digging down it  reveals the resposible calls are -[NSThread start] and +[NSThread exit]. I can't really make up what that's supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one of your threads is throwing an exception?  Exceptions in threads don't get reported in the debug console, you have to catch the exception in the thread.